# How can i use celery with different code base in API and workers

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, redis, celery

Currenty  I have one Ec2 Instance for  incomming API requests

1. User orders goes to queue in redis via celery task
2. I have 2 Ec2 instances processing queues

The problem is the code base is same on both API and celery workers. because e,g

I use `cutsomer.process_order(order_id)`

Then worker does the rest.

Is there any way that i separate API from worker code. I want to make API in separate code base and workers in separate code base

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your API code can call any Celery task without having the task source code available. Celery has a feature called [signatures](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html):

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(...)

process_order = app.signature('your-other-project.tasks.process_order')
result = process_order.delay(order_id)  # standard calling api works
print(result.get())
```

Just make sure both your API and worker connect to the same message broker and your worker actually has the task named in the signature.

Comment: Thanks for that. Also does the worker need to be djangon application as well or workers can just be plain python modules and tasks normal celery task?